# Hawkular Metrics not available on Openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, hawkular

Using :
Openshift: 3.7
OS : Windows 10 Prof
VM : Virtual Box

I'm using OC cluster up to operate Openshift  and do not receive and Hawkular metrics on the Openshift Web Console. A few articles seem to suggest that Hawkular needs port 8778 (Jolokia) is this true?

Also here is dump of images:

```
docker@openshift:~$ docker images
```

172.30.1.1:5000/default/karaf2-camel-amq (latest)
centos/postgresql-95-centos7 (none)
openshiftdemos/sonarqube (none)
registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-amq-6/amq63-openshift (none)
openshift/origin-haproxy-router  v3.7.0-rc.0
openshift/origin-deployer  v3.7.0-rc.0
openshift/origin-sti-builder v3.7.0-rc.0
openshift/origin v3.7.0-rc.0
openshift/origin-docker-registry v3.7.0-rc.0
openshift/origin-pod  v3.7.0-rc.0
registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-fuse-6/fis-karaf-openshift 1.0/2.0
sonatype/nexus3 (none)
fabric8/s2i-karaf 1.0/2.0
jenkins (none)

Comment: Did you provide the ``--metrics`` option to ``oc cluster up``?

Comment: Yes I've used the --metrics option. Shouldn't I see a pod(s) running in the Openshift-infra namespace? I'm kind of new to Openshift and not sure how to debug this one, any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: One of the problems with metrics is sometimes it works and sometimes it does. At least that is what I have found. In my case it never works the first time when not run that ``oc`` version before as it takes too long to pull images down and things don't start up quick enough. If you run ``docker images``, what are the images for OpenShift and what versions?

Comment: Hi Yes I did have did have Hawkular page appear on the last version however the pods never displayed the small graph on the dashboard. So reinstalling to a new version has regressed to present situation. Running docker images give me this output:

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton can't fit output on I've put in to the description

Comment: Can you try with ``oc`` version 3.7.1.

Comment: Trust you wanted me to run this command (oc version) with output of: 
oc v3.7.0-rc.0+e92d5c5  
kubernetes v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62  
features: Basic-Auth  

Server https://192.168.99.100:8443  
openshift v3.7.0-rc.0+e92d5c5  
kubernetes v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62